# Specify rowterminator when creating a file with SQLCMD

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcmd

How do you specify the the row terminator when outputting query results using sqlcmd?

bcp is not an option.

```
sqlcmd -E -s"   " -Q "Select * From SomeTable" -o C:\Output.txt  -W
```

What is the default row terminator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only choose column separator with -s. There is not option to specify row terminator.

So it is CR + LF because the output goes to command line. However, data may be truncated so you have to control the output width.

See [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773(SQL.90).aspx) for -s, -w, -W, -y, -Y etc

bcp may not be an option, as you say, but neither is row terminator in sqlcmd...